# Fill background color in <div> on hover as animation that starts from center point and goes outerwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Color must start from center point and with transition time. I have used all css transitions but no one gave me effect which i want.
Its not a duplicate because i want with css only.

Comment: What about a radial gradient transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a pseudo-element and transition the scale.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #f00;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div:hover:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```